# Reason for following output

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am taking a React JS course on Edx. In a test the output of following code was asked. I answered 1. But actually answer was 0. And it is actually rendering 0. Can anyone tell why?

```
var num = 0;

var element = <div> {num} </div>
ReactDOM.render(
    element,
    document.getElementById("root")
)
num++;

ReactDOM.render(
    element,
    document.getElementById("root")
)

num++;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `element` is an instance of `React.Element`. React elements are updating only after updating state via `setState()` or other state/props modifying lifecycle methods. In your case, the `element` have no any reasons to update - it behave like the copy of `num` variable was created, so any side changes will no affect `element` and `ReactDOM.render` will always render an `element` with initial value passed.

Hope, I explained it clearly and it will help you :)

Comment: more like final variable in java?